# Inserting a record in Oracle table with a value in different language

Tags: insert, oracle10g, multilingual

I am having problem with inserting a record in Oracle database table.

I have a table with a field name in Spanish “RÃ“TULO”. Just because of having fields, and values with some special characters, I cannot use the following simple insert command. I have also value for that field which has special characters.

I am pretty sure there is some setting in Oracle that allows me to accept different language (Spanish). Can somebody point me URL where I can learn about setting?

INSERT INTO "MyTable" ("RIDCODE" , "RÃ“TULO" ) values ('LVL1', 'Some Value with special characters');

I get the following error
SQL Error: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification
01747. 00000 -  "invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification"

*Cause:
*Action:

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SET ESCAPE '\'
INSERT INTO "MyTable" ("RIDCODE" , "RÃ\"TULO" ) 
values ('LVL1', 'Some Value with special characters');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able tackle Stated issue by setting the following option off while running insert and turning back it ON after I done with inserting.

SET DEFINE OFF;
SET SCAN OFF;

INSERT INTO "MyTable" ("RIDCODE" , "RÃ“TULO" ) values ('LVL1', 'Some Value with special characters');

SET DEFINE ON;
SET SCN ON;